# Question about isomorphism of modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

I have been reading the book of DeMeyer and Ingraham "Separable Algebras of Commutative Rings,"  where in page 129 they prove the following.
Let

$\bullet$ Let $S$ be a commutative ring and $G$ be a finite group such that $G$ acts on $S$ by automorphisms.

$\bullet$ Let [J] be an element of ${\bf Pic}(S)$ (the picard group of $S.$)

Then there is a $S$-module isomorphism $\sigma\cdot J\otimes_S J^*\cong \sigma\cdot S.$
Where $\sigma\cdot J=J$ and $\sigma\cdot S=S$ as sets and the action of $S$ on  $\sigma\cdot J$ and $\sigma\cdot S$ are given by $s\cdot x=\sigma(s)x,$ where $x\in S$ or $x\in J$ respectively.

I have not been able to prove that, actually i think that this isomorphism does not hold. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: The canonical map 
$$J\otimes_S J^*\to S, \quad x\otimes \phi \mapsto \phi(x)$$ 
is always an isomorphism for $J\in \mathrm{Pic}(S)$. The action of $G$ has nothing to do here. In the book they don't say there is a $G$-equivariant isomorphism.

Comment: I am not sure of what you are saying, i think we need to consider the action of $G.$ By the way do you have the book?

Comment: Yes I checked with the book, otherwise I would not say "In the book...".

Comment: Ok, (using the notations of the book) i think that in some way the fact that $_\sigma A\cong \sigma\cdot J\otimes_S J^*\otimes_S A,$  must imply $\sigma\cdot J\otimes_S J^*\cong \sigma\cdot S$ as $S$-modules.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't realize $\sigma\dot J$ has a different $S$-module strucutre than $J$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's simplify the notation a little bit and set $J' := \sigma\cdot J,\;S' := \sigma\cdot S$. Denote the multiplication induced by $\sigma$ by $s\bullet x := \sigma(s)x$. Since $S$ is commutative, $J'$ is a $S-S$-bimodule via $sxt := t(s\bullet x)$. Hence $J' \otimes_S J^\ast$ is a left $S$-module via $s\bullet (x\otimes f) := (s\bullet x)\otimes f$. Since $J$ represents an element from the Picard group, $F: J \otimes_S J^\ast \to S,\;x\otimes f \mapsto f(x)$ is an isomorphism of abelian groups. Moreover, 
$$F(s\bullet (x \otimes f))=F((s\bullet x)\otimes f)=F(\sigma(s)x\otimes f)=f(\sigma(s)x)=\sigma(s)f(x)=\sigma(s) F(x\otimes f)\\=s\bullet F(x\otimes f)$$
Hence $F$ is an isomorphism $J' \otimes_S J^\ast \cong S'$ of $S$-modules. q.e.d.

Comment: When you are working with $J'$ instead of $J,$ how do you know that $F$ is well defined?

Comment: The definition of $F$ only uses $J$ as right $S$-module and $J'=J$ as right $S$-module.

Comment: Thanks for the ideia, i was considering $J'$ as $S-S$-bimodule, where $s\bullet x= x\bullet s=\sigma(s)x,$ for any $s\in S$ and $x\in J'.$

Comment: So, may I ask why you didn't accept the answer and why you didn't upvote it so far ? Is there anything still left unclear to you ?

Comment: sorry Ralph. I already did.